# On variations of Erdős squarefree conjecture: presentation and a question as a simple case

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, prime-factorization, totient-function

I'm inspired in the so-called Erdős squarefree conjecture, [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Erd%C5%91s_squarefree_conjecture) from Wikipedia, to state in this post a question, involving a different arithmetic function, that due its  difficulty I feel as an exercise (in the Appendix I show another example), and in my next post I am going to add a different variation that I think that due its difficulty should be a conjecture.

In this post we denote the Euler's totient function as $\varphi(n)$, and it is well-known that satisfies $$\varphi(n)=n\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$$
for integers $n>1$.

Also is well-known the multiplicative formula for factorials, [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula) of Wikipedia.

**Computational fact.** In the segment of positive integers $1\leq n\leq 20000$, the integer $n=160$ is the last integer for which $$\binom{2n}{\varphi(n)}$$
is a square-free integer (has no repeated prime factors).

The sequence of binomial coefficients $$\binom{2n}{\varphi(n)}$$ having some repeated prime factors (when $n\geq 1$ runs over integers) starts as $$4,28,1820,18564\ldots$$

> **Question.** I belive that the following claim is true:
>
> *The binomial coefficient* $\binom{2n}{\varphi(n)}$ *is never squarefree for* $n>160$.
>
> Can you prove it or provide me hints? **Many thanks.**

Now I am going to add in next appendix a different example that I think more easy than previous, with the purpose to provide it to everyone that is interested in this kind of questions.

**Appendix:** We (exclude the case $n=2$) consider the arithmetic function $\binom{n\varphi(n)}{\sigma(n)}$, where $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ denotes the sum of divisors function. Then I believe that the following claim is true (you can to study it in your home, but feel free to add a counterexample as a comment if you find it).

**Claim.** The binomial coefficient $$\binom{n\varphi(n)}{\sigma(n)}$$ is never squarefree for $n>22$.

Comment: Concerning the second claim : I did not find such a number yet not divisible by one of the numbers $4,9,25,49,121,361$. My search is currently at $n=11\ 000$

Comment: Can you explain your comment in different words @Peter ? I am saying it since English isn't my native tongue and I don't understand it (you use the expression with two negations *I did not find such a number yet not divisible by one*). Many thanks.

Comment: That means that for $23\le n\le 11\ 000$, every number of the form in the second claim is divisible by one of the mentioned numbers, hence not squarefree.

Comment: Then are you saying that the second claim is obvious/has no mathematical meaning? Now I'm stuck @Peter

Comment: This is of course no proof, but it seems that a much stronger claim holds. I am now at $18\ 000$

Comment: Okey, my feeling as was said is that should be easy (more or less). Many thanks for your patience @Peter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75531/discussion-between-peter-and-user243301).

Comment: For the first claim, the set 4,9,25,49,121,169,289,361,529,2809 seems to be sufficient. I am at 40 000 , no counterexample.

Comment: No counterexample upto $24\ 000$ for the second claim. The numbers are growing much faster, so a test is more time consuming.

Comment: I was disconnected many  thanks @Peter