# Is there an easy criterion when $\binom{n}{m}$ is divisible by $q^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

To analyze questions like this

[On variations of Erdős squarefree conjecture: presentation and a question as a simple case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722490/on-variations-of-erd%c5%91s-squarefree-conjecture-presentation-and-a-question-as-a-s?noredirect=1#comment5620208_2722490)

it would be nice to have a simple criterion when $\binom{n}{m}$ is divisible by $q^2$, when $q$ is a prime and $n>m>1$ integers. We can assume $2m\le n$. Maybe creating pascal's triangle modulo $q^2$ gives a structure.

> Does anyone know a criterion that is easy to check without calculating the binomial coefficient ?

Comment: Count the number of factors $q$ in both $n!$ and $m!(n-m)!$ is what I'd do

Comment: @vrugtehagel And to do that, I just have to add the $p$-adic valuations with respect to $q$, right ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem

Comment: [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem) - Just count the number of carries when you add $m$ to $n-m$ in base $q$. If it has two or more carries, then $q^2| \binom{n}{m}$.